# File and directory autocompletion in remote shell

Tags: completion, shell, ssh

In my local shell, `completion-at-point` after `cd` returns a list of directories. However, when I ssh into a remote, Emacs thinks I'm still in my local home directory. How can I configure Emacs to give me remote directory autocompletion?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're doing `M-x shell` from a local directory and then doing `ssh` command in that buffer?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Have you tried using opening the remote directory using `C-x d` `/ssh:username@hostname:/directory-path` and then using `M-x shell` to open a remote shell?

Comment: Interesting! Now autocompletion works, but typing is intolerably slow.

Comment: Does it typing speed improve after a few minutes? Do you see any warnings in the *Messages* buffer?

Comment: Ten minutes later and typing speed hasn't improved. No warnings in the *Messages* buffer. Full output is here: http://pastebin.com/06wsB57n

Comment: Would you post your full emacs version string as a comment? After googling  [emacs tramp shell slow](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+tramp+shell+slow) I think you may have hit a bug.

Comment: GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS appkit-1343.16 Version 10.10.1 (Build 14B25)) of 2015-03-02 on Matthews-MacBook-Air.local

Comment: I tried disabling `global-projectile-mode` and the situation improved significantly!

Comment: Likewise after setqing projectile-mode-line to something that doesn't depend on `projectile-project-name`, so it looks like that is indeed the culprit.

Comment: Setqing `projectile-file-exists-remote-cache-expire` to `nil` also helps, though not as much.

Comment: Does the remote shell work okay now?

Comment: Well enough! Thank you for your help. If you would like to post this information as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this**

1. Open a remote directory in `dired` using `tramp`.

   <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> `/ssh:username@hostname:/path` <kbd>return</kbd>
2. Start a remote shell.

   <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell`

Comment: Is there a way to make something like this work with Emacs `term` or preferably `multi-term`