# Directory tracking in remote shell buffer

Tags: tramp, shell, completion, shell-mode, remote

I use the `shell` command via `C-u M-x shell` to open a shell on a remote server by giving as default directory the path to the remote server (e.g `/user@myserver.com:/home/user`) (which should have the same effect as the method described in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18046/9387)).

The directory of the buffer is at the beginning in sync with the directory of the shell (/user@myserver.com:/home/user`), and  tab completion works as expected giving me choices from the *remote* directory.

However, when you issue

```
cd ~
```

in the remote  shell, the buffer directory is set to the *local* home path, so that I get tab completion for local directories which obviously does not make any sense in the remote shell.

How can I keep the directory tracking in sync even when I use cd in the remote shell? - I'm using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on Centos, remote machine is Linux too.

Comment: Perhaps `C-u M-x shell` and `C-x d /ssh:username@hostname:/path return M-x shell` aren't equivalent? Does shell completion still work if you use the longer workaround?

Comment: Will check on Thursday when I'm back at that machine.

Comment: I have the same problem with `C-x d /ssh:username@hostname:/path return M-x shell `. In fact, I found out how to force the out-of-sync problem: just do `cd ~` in the remote shell! (Will update the question accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks for update! It sounds like you found the answer so you should post it! Are there any other commands like `cd ~` that will force shell to sync without doing a change directory?

Comment: Nooooo! I haven't found a solution - I just found out a straight forward way to *reproduce* the issue - see the updated question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I remember having this same issue years ago and vaguely recall reading something about calling the `pwd` command in shell to trigger `tramp` to refresh the remote execution path in the buffer.  I've been looking for the original source but haven't found it. Does using `pwd` help at all?

Comment: No, it's not that easy, because`pwd` does not show the remote host - I think the emacs command `shell-resync-dirs` has to be enhanced somehow to find out whether the shell is on a remote host...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best solution, but certainly a working one: Use `[dirtrack-mode]`. The following preparations are needed:

#### 1. On the remote machine:

Make sure the prompt of the remote shell contains the path including the server login **in TRAMP notation** (e.g. `/user@myserver.com:/home/user`). You can achieve this by setting `PS1` (e.g. in the .bashrc file on the remote server):

```
export PS1="[/\u@\h:\$PWD]$ "
```

#### 2. In your local Emacs:

Run the following list expression (e.g. in the `.emacs` file):

```
(setq dirtrack-list (quote ("^\\[\\(.*\\)\\]" 1)))
```

Then, after establishing a remote shell buffer, issue `M-x dirtrack-mode` in that buffer and - voila! - the buffer directory should follow the shell directory properly.

This solution isn't perfect, because it is necessary to print out in the remote shell the whole **absolute** path extended by the server login credentials. (Make sure the home directory gets expanded to the **full** path!) However it does work reliably.

Comment: Thanks for posting! Here's another good resource related to your answer: [http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5592/388](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5592/388).